# Load model in TensorFlow gives different result that original one

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using the TensorFlow library in Python. After creating a model and saving it, if I load the entire model, I get inconsistent results.

First of all, I'm using TensorFlow version 2.3.0.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

def get_new_model():
    model = Sequential([
        Conv2D(filters=16, input_shape=(32, 32, 3), kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv_1'),
        Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv_2'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4), name='pool_1'),
        Flatten(name='flatten'),
        Dense(units=32, activation='relu', name='dense_1'),
        Dense(units=10, activation='softmax', name='dense_2')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

checkpoint_path = 'model_checkpoints'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, save_weights_only=False, frequency='epoch', verbose=1)

model = get_new_model()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Until here no problem, I create the model, compile it and train it with some data. I also use ModelCheckpoint to save the model.
The problem comes when I try the following

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model2 = load_model(checkpoint_path)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
model2.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Then, the first evaluation returns an accuracy of 0.477, while the other returns an accuracy of 0.128, which is essentially a random choice.
What is the problem here? The two models are supposed to be identical, and actually, they give the same value for the loss function up to 16 decimal places.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue using toy example, but it is giving accuracy almost same. Can you share complete reproducible code or colab file of your code? so that we can try to help you. Thaanks!